# Github hosted domain works with https:// but not with http://

Tags: github-pages

I have a site hosted a site using guide https://pages.github.com/

I am able to see the site under https:// mydomain.com, but i don't see site under http:// mydomain.com

what is the cause.how to enable site under http:// mydomain.com ?

Answer (score 0):

What the interest to enable HTTP ?

Anyway, you cannot:

> HTTPS enforcement is required for GitHub Pages sites using a github.io
> domain that were created after June 15, 2016. If you created your site
> before June 15, 2016, you can manually enable HTTPS enforcement.

source: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/working-with-github-pages/securing-your-github-pages-site-with-https